# Recover Chromebook from attempt to install Windows

Tags: windows, chromebook

I have an ASUS Chromebook model C523N. I tried to install Windows following a guide like [this](https://www.lifewire.com/install-windows-on-chromebook-4778088) one. Unfortunately it didn't work, leaving my Chromebook in a state that I can't use it at all anymore. It's a few month ago now and I don't remember which screws I loosened and tightened.

It's showing "Booting from 'eMMC Device' failed; verify it contains a 64-bit UEFI OS. Press any key to continue booting'. It allows me to select from two boot devices, eMMC Device and UEFI Shell, but it doesn't display my USB stick. I also don't know what to do in that shell.

I do remember that I checked whether it's generally possible to do this with my Chromebook model. Is there any way to make it usable again or can I throw it away now?

Edit: I looked for the page that explains where the write protect screw/switch is in this Chromebook, but couldn't find it. I'm almost sure though that I put back everything where it was before. This it what it looks like in the inside: [image](https://ibb.co/8jrdtxN)

Comment: Did you try recreating the USB stick or using another one?

Comment: I have only one stick large enough to store Windows on it. I tried recreating it, and I can boot from the stick on other machines.

Comment: You will have to visual inspect the device to determine which screws you loosened or tightened.

Comment: How are you creating the stick?

Comment: I downloaded the MediaCreationTool from MS for Windows 10

Comment: If all else fails, and recovery (https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1080595?hl=en)  does not work, consider testing and installing Ubuntu: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-chromebook#1-overview before you dispose of the machine.

Comment: The thing is, all these installations require the Chromebook to go into Recovery Mode. I haven't seen that mode on my Chromebook. I tried all the mentioned combinations like ESC+Refresh+Power. It always shows the same message that it can't find a bootable OS. In fact, I haven't tried that (or to boot from USB) before I  started messing with it.